# Can you call UDF with Entity Framework 4 without using wizards?

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

A confession to make: without any permission, I rewrote the NerdDinner tutorial with .NET Framework 4 and Entity Framework 4, instead of LINQ to SQL, as I was fascinated with the concept of Code-first approach and Razor cshhtml template!

Nevertheless, when I reached the point where I have to use UDF to find nearest dinner, Entity Framework 4 proved to be very challenging.

Therefore, I would be grateful if anyone could point me to documentation about Entity Framework 4, which explains how to call UDF functions, as MSDN failed to get me around this – I spent 2 hours and forty five minutes on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857.aspx and it did not help. May be brain is become useless!!!

The answer I am looking for is: Can you call UDF with Entity Framework 4 without using wizards?

If the answer is yes, let me know how that can be done.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No Entity framework can't import UDFs. You can only import Stored procedures. UDFs can be called directly using standard SQL and `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery`. If you create data type which will have same properties as SQL result set, `SqlQuery` will be able to use that type.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is: yes, you can.

Take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456847(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Please always add the relevant parts of linked websites to you answer. This way your answer stays valid even if the website is not available anymore.

Comment: short, but to the point. Could you perhaps write the relevant content hear? That link may not live for ever, and knowing msdn, probably not long at all

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap UDFs with Stored Procs and import those.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_sel_MyCustomUDF]
    @Parameter int = null                   
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[udf_MyCustomUDF] Parameter) 

END
```